# Use createComponent in qml but the status is always error

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

When I use `Qt.createComponent` to create component dynamically, the stutas is always `Component.error` but I cannot understand the reason.

I used it like that:

```
Rectangle{
    function loadTest(){
        function finishCreation() {
            if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
                console.log("ready")
            } else if (component.status === Component.Error) {
                // Error Handling
                console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
            }
        }

        var component = Qt.createComponent("MyPage.qml");
        console.log(component.status)
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);

        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            var button = component.createObject(container);
            console.log("ready")
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("Completed Running!")
        loadTest()
    }
}
```

If the `MyPage.qml` does not exist in the `qrc` file, the error is

> qrc:/MyPage.qml:-1 File not found"

If I set the full path of `MyPage.qml`, I get a `Network error`.

When I add the `SeriesSelectionPage.qml` file to the resource file, it works. But it shouldn't be dynamic?

I just want to find a QML file and load it dynamically when the application executes so that the application can load different QML according to user operations.

Anyone knows how to do that? I'm going crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Qt.createComponent()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method) takes a `url` as its first argument. From the [`url` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-url.html):

> The url type refers to a resource locator (like a file name, for example). It can be either absolute, e.g. "http://qt-project.org", or relative, e.g. "pics/logo.png". A relative URL is resolved relative to the URL of the containing component.

So, as long as you're using relative URLs from within a file that is loaded from a `QRC` file, you'll need to use the `qrc` scheme:

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/MyPage.qml");
```

Comment: It will be better just add the QML file into resources and use "qrc:/" protocol in URL.

Comment: I was under the impression that OP wanted the end user to be able to choose a QML file... guess I misread.

Comment: Yes, you are right. looks like your first version of answer is more correct :) Sorry

Comment: OP wrote "When I add the "SeriesSelectionPage.qml" to qrc file. It works."

Comment: No, I think you're right and I just read the question incorrectly! Haha. :)

Comment: @N1ghtLight Jeez...I think it's the first interpretation, i.e. loading a file on the basis of user interactions. As a matter of fact, we can be all wrong. :D

Comment: Thank you all. I'm so sorry that my English is too weak to express clearly.

Comment: What url could I use if I want to create Qt provided component (in my case a MessageDialog)? I clearly dont want to hardcode /opt/Qt5/blabla into my code.

Comment: @DanielBrunner you have to wrap the Qt component in your own QML file.